# Internet Explorer 11's Javascript console won't open

Tags: javascript, console, internet-explorer-11, windows-explorer

I need to use IE11's Javascript console, but I can't find the way to open it... I'm pressing F12 and there's no response.

Is there any way I can open it?

[image]

Comment: How about `right-click` and then `inspect-element`?

Comment: Is there no Tools menu in IE11?

Comment: you mean right-click and then inspeccionar el elemento

Comment: Does IE HAVE right-click and inspeccionar el elemento at all?

Comment: @VisioN -  I think debugging tools in browsers counts as *software tools commonly used by programmers;*. I doubt casual Internet users need the JavaScript console.

Comment: @mplungjan: It does as a general rule, yes, are you asking the OP if it does in their environment?

Comment: @BSMP Agreed...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am asking because I have never seen it on IE10 which is the highest version I have access to.

Comment: @mplungjan: Ah. Yes, IE11 has it.

Comment: I don't need to inspect the source code, I need to catch the Javascript output in the console.

Comment: Might be trivial, but since you're showing the about dialog as a screen shot - as long as the "About" window is open, F12 doesn't work. Close it, then click on the title of your browser window to make it the active window, then press F12.

Comment: @Matt I'm wasn't trying to open it while About windows was opened, I just made and screenshot to show the version. The problem isn't solved but I know why happens, thanks.

Comment: Does it occur on a company's PC? Maybe there is a group policy preventing it from opening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of possibilities here:

1. Dev Tools is disabled, either because you're not on a real page (for instance, the default home page when you first open it), or because your organization's Active Directory configuration doesn't allow it.
2. Something else must be consuming the F12 (for instance, if you're running a virtual machine, perhaps the virtual machine software is using F12 as the "host" key).

If Dev Tools isn't disabled, you can always open Dev Tools from the gear menu:

[image]

Comment: 1: That was what I thought...

Comment: Hi, Gear menu isn't showing Dev Tools. I'm not using a virtual machine. The computer I'm using is under an enterprise network, but I remember I could open it before. Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid: Talk to your IT people, sounds like they disabled it.

Comment: Indeed, my organization's Active Directory configuration doesn't allow it. It's fun because we are the developers and we can't develop in IE. By the way, do you know any other browser that works simillar to IE?, so I can work with it. Thanks.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid: Get them to change the policy. An IT policy that prevents you doing your job is a bad IT policy, my experience is that as long as there's a reason, you can get it changed (for the people who are developers). Meanwhile, sure, you can use Chrome and such, IE11 is reasonably standards-compliant, but you still need to test and occasionally need to debug specifically in IE.